# Fill listview with the same method for Activity and SupportMapFragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, supportmapfragment

I filling a `ListView` with information from a webserver.
In the `Activity`, my `ListAdapeter` is working perfectly, but when I'm trying to use it in a `Fragment`, I can't iniziallizate my adapter.

**ListAdapter.java**

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    MainActivity main;

    public ListAdapter(MainActivity main){
        this.main = main;
    }
    //Some methods.
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class ListReportsFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    @Override
    public ListView list;
        public ListAdapter adapter;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            //.........
            list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            adapter = new ListAdapter(this);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
//........
    }
```

There is working perfectly, but, when I try to use it in my Fragment:

**ListReportsFragment**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(new MainActivity());
        list.setAdapter(adapter); //This is the line 58
    }
```

I get the error
`java.lang.NullPointerExceptionlayout.ListReportsFragment.onActivityCreated(ListReportsFragment.java:58)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(new MainActivity());
```

to

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
```

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new object of MainActivity that's why you getting error

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(new MainActivity());
```

pass MainActivity to fragment then pass it to ListAdapter

```
MainActivity main;

public ListReportsFragment(MainActivity main){
    this.main = main;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(main);
    list.setAdapter(adapter); //This is the line 58
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(new MainActivity());
```

to

```
adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
```

Also, move this part of the code to onCreateView() as follows:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    adapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity());
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
//what to do on item click goes here!
    });
    return rootView;
}
```